# A manhwa that the female lead had her soul infused with another body so she can have revenge on the people that betrayed her

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, supernatural

From what I remember the female lead met the emperor when they were young and they were friends. As time went she killed for him so he could ascend the throne and she fell in love with him. When he was emperor he found her as a threat and the people in the council wanted her dead. Especially the elven knight since she was jealous cause the female lead was head of the knights. A male found her in the ice dungeon they put her after her tongue was cut off and her legs were crushed, so a male that could change his hair from white to black also a prince without a kingdom transfused her soul into another body so she could help him seek revenge of killing the king or emperor.

Comment: Can you give any additional details? Can you indicate more or less when you read this?

Comment: What colour was the female lead's hair?

Comment: Before her soul was infused she had i think ginger curly hair then when her soul was infused the owner of the real body had long blonde hair

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly *[Justice for the Villainess](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/justice-for-the-villainess)*.

> "I won't rest until they're dead." Charlotte has no qualms about murder if it means her beloved Prince Albert can ascend to the throne. But when he accuses her of treason and leaves her to rot in prison, she learns that loyalty is no virtue. 5 years later, Count Kaitel appears before her with a request: “Won’t you kill the emperor?”

The synopsis covers the betrayal and revenge themes. The main character, Charlotte, met the 7th prince and future emperor and fell in love with him. Partially with the promise of her becoming empress, she assassinated the other candidates for the throne and made him emperor, only for him to make someone else empress and then accuse her of jealously plotting against the new empress.

She's thrown into a prison in a snowy area to die. It's not exactly an "ice prison", just a prison in a desolate snowy area. Her legs are depicted as "useless", but unless there's a later flashback, her legs were not explicitly broken. Additionally, her tongue wasn't cut off, as she's still able to speak.

If you read the original novel (I haven't), it's possible the details are more explicit/cruel there - that happens sometimes, and could explain the discrepancy.

She's rescued from prison by the adopted son of an archduke. He takes her to a temple in a destroyed kingdom that has immortality and soul transfer magic. It turns out he's the prince of this destroyed kingdom, and has white hair but uses magic to change it to black. He uses the soul transfer magic to transfer her body to that of a comatose blonde maid.

[image: Old and new body]

Her original body has slightly curly black hair, not ginger, but the art style sometimes gives it a bit more color. The bit with the elven knight might be explained in a future chapter; this is just based on the first four.